# How to run any command in Google Cloud shell using cloud shell API?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-workspace, google-cloud-shell

I have a script on my device. I want to run some command in GCP shell from my device. I have seen there is an API called `cloud shell API`. I don't how it's work.

so, How can I run some commend in GCP cloud shell from my local device using cloud shell API?

Comment: I wrote a Golang application that shows how to use the Cloud Shell API: https://github.com/jhanley-com/google-cloud-shell-cli-go

Comment: @JohnHanley I don't know Golang. can how to do?

Comment: Google search for other resources or try to learn to read Go.